# Divergence of vector fields intuitive understanding

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

I am troubled by the idea of positive and negative divergence of a vector field. I understand that the idea of e.g.  positive  div is that a gas expands everywhere (for the velocity field of a gas example of the wikipedia page for divergence). However what troubles me is that if the gas expands everywhere then at any given point vectors are going outwards,  OK, BUT also, since there are gas molecule behind every other given molecule,  the would be the same vector filed line (velocity) going in the space (of which another is going out)...if fluid is expanding out of point p well the fluid is also expanding  behind p so...so in the end that looks to me exactly the same as the 0 divergence where the  flux in is exactly the flux out! See my problem!? Can anyone help, I obviously see I am missing something...but what?(btw same problem for negative div).

I can imagine one solution is that the field is faster and faster at every point so that arrows representing the vector field are strictly longer at each point in the expanding direction..? Maybe this is the correct idea of "expanding " ..but it does not seem to be clearly stated  usually?

Answer (score 1):

"Gas expanding" is not a very good analogue. Three different scenarios are possible, for example each one of these is different $$\nabla \cdot v=0,$$ $$\nabla \cdot (\rho v) = 0,$$ $$ \frac{D\rho v}{Dt}=0,$$ where $v$ is vector field of velocity, $\rho$ is scalar field of density, $D/Dt=\partial/\partial t+v\partial/\partial x+u\partial/\partial y+w\partial/\partial z$ is operator of transmission. In some cases these equations are coinciding, in other cases they differ. Only third one is true material equation, which in this case is *matter conservation* equation, but it allows both density and velocity fields to have divergence.

Better just start from very simple approach from electrostatics, where everything is evident. You have Coulomb forces and Coulomb fields with charges. You obtain electrical field from your distribution of charges $\nabla\cdot E = \rho/\epsilon_0$, where $\rho$ is density of charge. You can *feel* this divergence as when you put create a charge, the associated vector flux through the surface surrounding it will be $\Phi_E=Q/\epsilon_0$. Electrostatics is much simpler then hydrodynamics.

Comment: Ok, but lets say in a "simplified picture" do you agree woth my answer (w.r.t. Wikipedia's example of expanding/contracting gas, again simplified)?

Comment: @Machupicchu When your gas is incompressible $\rho=1$ then your inflows and outflows will be points of divergence, but everywhere else divergence is zero.

Comment: I m not sure i completely understand, but my question is: does the simplified analogy of the velocity field when expanding is accelerating thus speed (=magnitude of velocity) is increasing at each point i.e. "longer" vectors conceptually because of acceleration? And if div=0 then same lenght vectors everywhere = constant speed?

Comment: w.r.t. a velocity vector field

Comment: Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just found the answer myself..
Taking the expanding or contracting gas example, where the vector field is the gas's velocity field.

If the gas is expanding, it must have positive divergence (cf. Wikipedia  article about divergence), and the divergence being computed as a sum of (partial) derivatives, to have "longer arrows" at each point in the direction of expansion, would imply the gas is accelerating. This makes sense wrt derivatives, since we know that acceleration is the derivative of speed wrt time. Therefore an expanding gas is accelerating!

Same and opposite for contraction, the gas is decelerating therefore reducing the length of arrows.

Finally, for the nul divergence  we would have constant speed everywhere,  therefore the derivative (=acceleration) would be null everywhere and so divergence=0 at each point!